# How to find something in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have the next program.
And I would like if you could explain to me how to find for example in a classroom I want to find a classroom, how do I do it?
For example I want to add a course that I already added to a classroom, and I'm quite new in c# and lists (I came from C) so I would really appreciate your help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Maman15cs

{


public class ClassRoom
{

    public string ClassNumber;
    public int NumberofPlaces;
    public int[,] DayandHour = new int[6,8];

    public static ClassRoom AddClassRoom()
    {
        var classRoom = new ClassRoom();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Class number, the Number of places\n");
        classRoom.ClassNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        classRoom.NumberofPlaces = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Good, now enter the Day(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and after that you put the courses' number that are that day (In Order)");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {

               classRoom.DayandHour[i,j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }

        }
        return classRoom;
    }

    public static ClassRoom AddCourseInClassroom(ClassRoom classroom)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}


public class Course
    {
        public string CourseName;
        public int CourseNumber;
        public int StudentsNumber;
        public string TeacherName;
        public string ClassNumber;



  public static Course AddCourse()
    {
        Course newCourse = new Course(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Course's name, course's number, students number, teacher's name, and class' number\n");
        newCourse.CourseName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        newCourse.CourseNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        newCourse.StudentsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        newCourse.TeacherName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        newCourse.ClassNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        return newCourse;
    }
}

public class Program
{

     void Main()
    {
        var course = new List<Course>();
        var classroom = new List<ClassRoom>();



        int actionChoice;


         while(true){
         Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do? (Enter number): \n  1) Add a new Course \n 2)Add a new class room \n 3)Add an existing course to an existing classroom \n 4)Read the information of a specific classroom \n 5)Read the information of all the classrooms \n 6)Read the information of a specific course \n 7)Delete a specific course \n 8)Update courses in the Time Table \n 9)Exit the program  \n");
         actionChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

         switch (actionChoice)
         {

             case 1: //Add a new Course

                 var new_course =  Course.AddCourse();                     
                 course.Add(new_course);

               break;

             case 2:

                var new_classRoom = ClassRoom.AddClassRoom();
                classroom.Add(new_classRoom);

               break;

             case 3:

               Console.WriteLine("Enter the course's number and the classroom's number");
               var courseNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               var classroomNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

               course.Find(courseNumber);




               break;

             case 9:

               return;



         }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your list?  I don't see one here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx  What I do see is an array of `int[,]`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you can use LINQ, this is pretty easy:

```
var foundCourse = course.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CourseNumber == courseNumber)

if (foundCourse != null)
{
  // You're now interacting with the course we found
}
```

If you can't use LINQ, let me know and I'll explain a less efficient/clean way.

Edit to show a different way:
For a more simple way (without LINQ), you could just do it in a for loop or foreach loop.  For example:

```
private Course FindCourse(int courseNumber, List<Course> courses)
{
    foreach(Course course in courses)
    {
        if(course.CourseNumber == courseNumber)
            return course;
    }

    // Not found, return null
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I will try to learn it but yes I would like if you could explain another way.

Comment: I need to access the list 

var foundRoom = classroom.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClassNumber == classroomNumber);
                    if (foundRoom != null)
                    {
                     I need to change the list so It would be something like classroom = foundRoom.AddCourseInClassroom();

                    }

Comment: So how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
List<ClassRoom> result = yourlist.Where(x=>x.CourseName=="yourdesidredcourse").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

[I would recommend this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) if you would like to learn about the api for lists in C#. But essentially, searching can be done easily using the Where method and a predicate (which is a method that returns a bool indicating whether or not the element meets a particular criteria). consider:

```
var matches = courses.Where( e => e.CourseNumber == providedCourseNumber );
```

This snippet reads: matches will be an IEnumerable of Courses whose CourseNumber is equivalent to the providedCourseNumber.